# How to sort 2 dependent ArrayLists?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Arraylists. One contain title of song and another contain location of song. How can i sort them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//loop start
     //some code
     arrayList.add(currenttitle+"////.////"+currentartist+" | "+currentalbum+"////.////"+currentlocation);
     //some code
//loop end
Collections.sort(arrayList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++) {
    arrayListloc.add(arrayList.get(i).split("////.////")[2]);
}
```

This fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Class` Like

```
public class Song{
  private String title;
  private String location;
}
```

Make a `List<Song>` and copy all the  title and corresponding location of song in same object and save them to new List. and now Sort the new List.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom class `Song`

```
class Song {
    private String songName, SongUrl;

    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }

    public String getSonglink() {
        return Songlink;
    }

    public void setSonglink(String songlink) {
        Songlink = songlink;
    }
}
```

Instead of using two ArrayLists, Create single Arraylist with this class and use it as data source.

```
List<Song> songData = new ArrayList<Song>();
```

Now you can easily sort this using `Comparator`

```
Collections.sort(songData, new Comparator<Song>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {
        return o1.getSongName().compareTo(o2.getSongName());
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to access the arraylist with index how can i do that in it